# tensorflow static_rnn: Fetch tensor created in cell call

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

### The Goal

Let's say I want to run an RNN on variable-length data, such as text, but I know a maximum length and I even know that within a single batch every sample has the same length. So `static_rnn` and `dynamic_rnn` come to mind as candidates.

In addition, I want to use a custom cell that computes some additional quantities that are not recurrent (i.e. they are not needed in further steps) yet are needed in later computations.
While I could make them simply part of the cell output and fetch them from the result of the `rnn` call, I'd prefer to leave the output unchanged and access them by name.

### The Code

The following snippet exemplifies the problem

- `MyGRUWrapper` is a simple Wrapper that computes such an *interesting* quantity
- I use `static_rnn` **with** the `sequence_length` argument
- After creating the RNN, I get a handle on the interesting tensors by their name
- At runtime I fetch the result along with one of the interesting quantities (there is one per timestep)

import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np
    import re
    from tensorflow.contrib.rnn import GRUCell, RNNCell

```
# A simple cell wrapper that computes some "interesting" quantity
# in addition to calling the wrapped cell
class MyGRUWrapper(RNNCell):
  def __init__(self, cell, reuse=None):
    super(MyGRUWrapper, self).__init__(_reuse=reuse)
    assert(isinstance(cell, GRUCell))
    self.cell = cell

  @property
  def state_size(self):
      return self.cell.state_size

  @property
  def output_size(self):
    return self.cell.output_size

  def call(self, inputs, state):
    new_state, _ = self.cell(inputs, state)

    tf.identity(tf.nn.l2_loss(new_state, name="interesting_quantity"))

    return new_state, new_state

# (somewhat native) helper to fetch tensors by name
def simple_get_tensor_by_name(pattern):
  all_nodes = tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node
  nodes = list(filter(lambda t : re.match(pattern, t.name) , all_nodes))
  tensors = [tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("%s:0" % (t.name)) for t in nodes]
  return tensors

# Define a variable batch_size, variable length, but fixed maximum length RNN   
batch_size = 16
input_size = 100
max_length = 10

inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, max_length, input_size], name="input")
length = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

cell = GRUCell(100)
cell = MyGRUWrapper(cell)

states, _ = tf.nn.static_rnn(cell, tf.unstack(inputs, axis=1), dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=length)

# Fetch our interesting quantities of which there will be max_length many
interesting_quantities = simple_get_tensor_by_name(".*interesting_quantity.*")
assert(len(interesting_quantities) == max_length)

# Run the graph with dummy input
with tf.Session() as session:
  session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

  batch_length = np.random.randint(1, max_length)
  inpt = np.random.rand(batch_size, max_length, input_size)

  out, q = session.run([states, interesting_quantities[0]], feed_dict = {inputs : inpt, length :[batch_length] * batch_size})
```

### The Problem

I do understand that for an input of length `t<max_length`, there is no point in fetching a quantity at step `t'>t`. However, for timesteps that are actually computed -- such as step 0 in the example -- I would expect that I can fetch the quantity.

However, I get a
`ValueError: Operation 'rnn/cond/rnn/my_gru_wrapper/interesting_quantity' has been marked as not fetchable`
in the run command.

I guess this is a consequence of `static_rnn` using `tf.cond` at every timestep when `sequence_length` is being used.

Is there any way around this without giving up on providing the length (as this is crucial for performance) and without packing all of this into the cell output? Also ideas using `dynamic_rnn` are welcome but I guess the internal use of `tf.while` does not make things easier.

(Tested in TF 1.2.0 and 1.4.0-rc4)